# How to get the LogEventOn Values from Advanced Properties?

Tags: powershell, iis

I want to generate a report from all the Properties for every entry in the IIS Application Pool.

I have problems to get the Values from the red marked Properties.

[image]

All the other Values was not a problem to read.. Just with the "logEventOn"-Values. Ill show you my code first:

```
$ConfigSection = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.applicationHost/applicationPools"

$SitesCollection = Get-IISConfigCollection -ConfigElement $ConfigSection

$Site = Get-IISConfigCollectionElement -ConfigCollection $SitesCollection -ConfigAttribute @{"name" = "DefaultAppPool"}

$Elem = Get-IISConfigElement -ConfigElement $Site -ChildElementName "recycling"

Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $Elem -AttributeName "logEventOnRecycle"
```

This gives me the following output, these are the Properties from "logEventOn":

> Time,Requests,Schedule,Memory,IsapiUnhealthy,OnDemand,ConfigChange,PrivateMemory

Now I tried to edit the "Get-IISConfigAttributeValue" Command. I tried with different options like:

```
Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $Elem -AttributeName "logEventOnRecycle/@Time"
Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $Elem -AttributeName "logEventOnRecycle/Time"
Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $Elem -AttributeName "logEventOnRecycle.Time"
```

But i always get the Error Message that the Value does not exist.

How do i have to shape the command to get these Values?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but would `(Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $Elem -AttributeName "logEventOnRecycle").Time` do it?

Comment: Sadly it doenst.. im really stuck on this, searching for a solution quite a while :(

Comment: Based on the schema, it is a flag field, https://github.com/lextm/iis_schema/blob/master/IIS_schema.xml#L161 So you need to do some math to calculate the values.

Comment: I have no idea how to start with this, but im gonna google a little, maybe ill find it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Lex Li who found the schema definition for this, you can read the flag values like below and convert to Boolean (True/False) values.

```
# get the Idle Timeout value
$ProcessModel = Get-IISConfigElement -ConfigElement $Site -ChildElementName "processModel"
$flags = $ProcessModel.Attributes["logEventOnProcessModel"].Value
$idleTimeout = [bool]($flags -band 1)             # Idle Time-out Reached

# get the values recorded under Recycle
$Elem = Get-IISConfigElement -ConfigElement $Site -ChildElementName "recycling"
$flags = $Elem.Attributes["logEventOnRecycle"].Value
$onRecycle = @{
    'Time'           = [bool]($flags -band 1)     # Specific Time
    'Requests'       = [bool]($flags -band 2)     # Request Limit Exceeded
    'Schedule'       = [bool]($flags -band 4)     # Regular Time Interval
    'Memory'         = [bool]($flags -band 8)     # Virtual Memory Limit Exceeded
    'IsapiUnhealthy' = [bool]($flags -band 16)    # Isapi Reported Unhealthy
    'OnDemand'       = [bool]($flags -band 32)    # Manual Recycle
    'ConfigChange'   = [bool]($flags -band 64)    # Application Pool Configuration Changed
    'PrivateMemory'  = [bool]($flags -band 128)   # Private Memory Limit Exceeded
}
# use these values like '$onRecycle.ConfigChange' etc.
```

I though it best to create a hashtable for the 'OnRecycle' values to keep them together, but you're free to put them all in separate variables ofcourse if that is what you want.

Comment: Hello Theo
First: Thanks a lot for the Code! I really appreciate it a lot!

But it always gives me this "Error: Cannot convert value "IdleTimeout" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format.""
I tried a some things, but nothing helped.. Its not possible to convert this string into a int32, as its only characters.. i dont really understand where the error is coming from.
Can you help with this?

Comment: @LucaS I think I see why. The `IdleTimout` is under a different child element. Try `$ProcessModel = Get-IISConfigElement -ConfigElement $Site -ChildElementName "processModel" ; $flags = Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $ProcessModel -AttributeName "logEventOnProcessModel" ; $idleTimeout = [bool]($flags -band 1)             # Idle Time-out Reached`. Because comments here do not accept linebreaks, I have updated my answer. I cannot check this for myself, so let me know?

Comment: thanks for your effort.. I can see you added the Line with $ProcessModel, but besides this its the same? or do i miss something? i copied the change, but it still gives me exact the same error.. Any other ideas? *hopefull*

Comment: No, it is not just the line with `$ProcessModel`, but also the line beneath that has changed. IdleTimeout is inside an element called `processModel` in the schema. The Recycle attributes are inside another element called "recycling". That line you already had and captured the element in a variable called `$Elem`.  For `IdleTimeout` we need to use the `$ProcessModel` variable.

Comment: Ok i saw what you mean, but i already made this change.. and i still get the failure "Cannot convert value "IdleTimeout" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."".. any ideas?

Comment: @LucaS Strange.. Then what does `Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $ProcessModel -AttributeName "logEventOnProcessModel"
` return exactly?

Comment: If it returns a string instead of an integer (flags) value, then your iis_schema.xml is different from the one I saw. Check `%SystemRoot%\System32\Inetsrv\Config\Schema`

Comment: i found the file, and the part with "logEventOnProcessModel" looks like this
<attribute name="logEventOnProcessModel" type="flags" defaultValue="IdleTimeout" >
          <flag name="IdleTimeout" value="1"/>
        </attribute>

I think thats the same as the file from LexLi no?

Comment: @LucaS I've been fiddling with this quite some time and finally managed to get a numeric value.. It seems this `$flags = $ProcessModel.Attributes["logEventOnProcessModel"].Value` is the only way it worked for me. I have changed the code in my answer. If there is a better way I would love to hear, but I couldn't find any example anywhere, so..

Comment: oh wow, i appreciate this a lot man!! i almost gave up on this! thanks to you, i managed to generate the whole report and everything is working now! perfect to go into the weekend ;) thanks so much theo!! enjoy your weekend, and thanks again for the time you invested to help me!